# Google Apps Scripting - Generic Headers in Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Quick look where I normally bother people tells me here is the new place to ask questions!

I have been making a script to create documentation generated from spreadsheet data which was in turn generated from a Google form. (Hope that makes sense...)

Anyway, I have been very successful with a lot of searching and bit of help but now I want to make my script homogeneous so I don't need to tinker with it when I want to setup new forms etc.

I have the getRowData function going from Googles script tutorials but instead of calling the row data from the normalised Headers i would like these to be generic i.e. Column1, Column2 etc.

I've pasted the tutorial function below, it passes the data to another function which normalizes the headers to use as objects, I was thinking thats where I could make them generic but I'm not sure how to get started on it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,

Alex

```
// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range; 
// Returns an Array of objects.
function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
  columnHeadersRowIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range.getRowIndex() - 1;
  var numColumns = range.getEndColumn() - range.getColumn() + 1;
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(columnHeadersRowIndex, range.getColumn(), 1, numColumns);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
//  Browser.msgBox(headers.toSource());
  return getObjects(range.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
//  return getObjects(range.getRowIndex);
}
```

Comment: Actually as I think further on this, I think it would be better to scrap the tutorial function and make a new called something like generalizeHeader which i can pass the array of values to and then convert them into generic names like columnOne, columnTwo ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the columns using their index, why parse them to object at all? Just use the plain `getValues`!

```
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var row2 = values[1];
var cell_in_col4 = row2[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing "var" when declaring your columnHeadersRowIndex variable.

Comment: columnHeadersRowIndex is already defined as an argument... you can't declare it again, it won't work anymore...